# Java JIT/Inline compiler memory causing container OOMKilled event

Tags: java, compilation, containers, jit, java-17

I recently upgraded my web application from OpenJDK 8 to OpenJDK 17. During upgrade testing we realized that containers are being killed with OOMKilled (137) status.

VM parameters provided for application

```
-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=40 -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=256m  -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -server -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,suspend=n -XX:+UseG1GC -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -DIGNITE_UPDATE_NOTIFIER=false -Xlog:gc:/var/log/service-gclog.txt  -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/var/log/dump -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+FlightRecorder
```

POD memory is having 2GB allocated to it.

The java log prints "Killed". This is why I started looking in Native memory consumption, So started capturing details with `jcmd <PS_ID> VM.native_memory` command during test.

**Test:** Test consist of creating purchase order(~7 API per order) via jmeter. The service fails around 50 order creation.

Below are the initial readings

```
-                  Compiler (reserved=1013KB, committed=1013KB)
                            (malloc=849KB #1601) 
                            (arena=165KB #5)
```

Below are the readings just before POD got killed

```
-                  Compiler (reserved=678349KB, committed=678349KB)
                            (malloc=1729KB #2690) 
                            (arena=676621KB #13)
```

Meaning Compiler was using ~678MB before the container died.

**Is there a way to limit this memory consumption?**

Heap utilization is still within 1G and GC is working as expected.

After this I have tried multiple options but nothing that provides real effect on compiler memory except disabling inline itself with `-XX:-Inline`  flag. This flag of-course has impact on performance which is why im still looking for another option.
So far I have tried

- Disabling IncrementalInline
- Enabling IncrementalInlineForceCleanup
- Disabling Inline
- Disabling InlineUnsafeOps - Reduces memory consumption upto certain limit but as soon as I add another test scenario(invoke another api apart from order creation) memory consumption increases and OOMKiled is triggered.
- Reduce MaxInlineLevel to 9
- Disabling UseInlineCaches
- Disabling TieredCompilation

On the container side I am using Alpine-3.17.3 with cgroupv2 configuration

I tried increasing POD memory to 2.5G (Thinking that jdk17 might need more native memory to do C2 level optimization )but the OOMKilled event still occurs

```
Continer Memory Details 

Runtime.availableProcessors: 2
OperatingSystemMXBean.getAvailableProcessors: 2
OperatingSystemMXBean.getTotalPhysicalMemorySize: 2684354560
OperatingSystemMXBean.getFreePhysicalMemorySize: 1241612288
OperatingSystemMXBean.getTotalSwapSpaceSize: 0
OperatingSystemMXBean.getFreeSwapSpaceSize: 0
```

**Is there anything else I should be investigating in ?**